# English translation of the STTS tagset

Tags: nlp

The most common part-of-speech tagset for German is the [STTS tagset](http://www.ims.uni-stuttgart.de/projekte/corplex/TagSets/stts-table.html). I need an English translation of the explanations for each tag. Not being a linguist I don't feel comfortable (let alone qualified) for translating this myself.

Google turned up nothing, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's nothing here that is surprising if you know English linguistic terminology.
If not, this may not have helped

ADJA    attributive adjective   [das] große [Haus] = [the] big [house]
ADJD    adverbial or predicative adjective  [er fährt] schnell, [er ist] schnell
= [he drives] quickly, [he is quick] (CB "quickly" and "quick" are both "schnell"

ADV Adverb          schon, bald, doch = already, soon, doch has no English equivalent

APPR    Preposition, left part of circumposition    in [der Stadt], ohne [mich] 
APPRART Preposition with article folded in  im [Haus], zur [Sache]
APPO    Postposition    [ihm] zufolge, [der Sache] wegen
APZR    Right part of circumposition    [von/APPR jetzt] an/APZR

ART definite or indefinite article  der, die, das, ein, eine

CARD    cardinal number zwei [Männer], [im Jahre] 1994

FM  foreign word    [Er hat das mit ``] A big fish ['' übersetzt]

ITJ interjection    mhm, ach, tja

KOUI    subordinating conjunction with ``zu'' and infinitive    um [zu leben], anstatt [zu fragen]
KOUS    subordinating conjunction with sentence weil, daß, damit, wenn, ob
KON coordinating conjunction    und, oder, aber
KOKOM   comparative conjunction als, wie

NN  common noun Tisch, Herr, [das] Reisen
NE  proper noun Hans, Hamburg, HSV

PDS demonstrative pronoun that substitutes  dieser, jener 
PDAT    demonstrative pronoun that adds an attribute    jener [Mensch]

PIS indefinite pronoun that substitutes keiner, viele, man, niemand
PIAT    indefinite pronoun that adds an attribute, no article   kein [Mensch], irgendein [Glas]
PIDAT   indefinite pronoun that adds an attribute, with article [ein] wenig [Wasser], [die] beiden [Brüder]

PPER    non-reflexive personal pronoun  ich, er, ihm, mich, dir

PPOSS   substituting possessive pronoun meins, deiner
PPOSAT  attribute adding posessive pronoun  mein [Buch], deine [Mutter]

PRELS   substituting relative pronoun   [der Hund ,] der
PRELAT  attribute adding relative pronoun   [der Mann ,] dessen [Hund]

PRF reflexive personal pronoun  sich, einander, dich, mir

PWS substituting interrogative pronoun  wer, was
PWAT    attribute adding interrogative pronoun  welche [Farbe], wessen [Hut]
PWAV    adverbial interrogative or relative pronoun warum, wo, wann, worüber, wobei

PAV pronominal adverb   dafür, dabei, deswegen, trotzdem

PTKZU   ``zu'' before infinitive    zu [gehen]
PTKNEG  Negation particle   nicht
PTKVZ   particle part of separable verb [er kommt] an, [er fährt] rad
PTKANT  answer particle ja, nein, danke, bitte
PTKA    particle associated with adverb or adjective    am [schönsten], zu [schnell]

TRUNC   first member of compound noun   An- [und Abreise]

VVFIN   full finite verb    [du] gehst, [wir] kommen [an]
VVIMP   full imperative komm [!]
VVINF   full infinitive gehen, ankommen
VVIZU   full infinitive with "zu"   anzukommen, loszulassen
VVPP    full past participle    gegangen, angekommen
VAFIN   auxilliary finite verb  [du] bist, [wir] werden
VAIMP   auxilliary imperative   sei [ruhig !]
VAINF   auxilliary infinitive   werden, sein
VAPP    auxilliary past participle  gewesen
VMFIN   modal finite verb   dürfen
VMINF   modal infinitive    wollen
VMPP    modal past participle   gekonnt, [er hat gehen] können

XY  Non word with special characters in 3:7, H2O, D2XW3

\$, comma   ,
\$. sentence ending punctuation . ? ! ; :
\$( other sentence signs; sentence internal - ,

Hope that helps a bit

Comment: Thanks a bunch. The thing is that I need this for my diploma thesis, so I want to get it right (even though it's only in the appendix). I'm probably going to leave the original German definition and just add your/mine translation as a note.

Comment: Thanks, can you link to some source?

Answer (score 1):

A document providing an English description and some examples for the STTS tagset is available in the website of the University of Cambridge (it is unclear to me what is the original source of the paper).

https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~sht25/papers/stts.pdf